# new objects created in Vuejs getting updated to last value

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vuejs but am having an issue with some code.

I am trying to 'flatten' a series of line_items of orders into a list of items and then create meta information for each object. The first part works fine but it appears as if the reactive nature of Vuejs is causing the last value of these newly created objects to extend across all previous incarnations.

I have created a fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/trestles/ruj7hzcf/3/

I presume that the problem is in creating my item (~ line 70 in fiddle).

```
  // here's the problem - why is quantity being updated to the last value? 
  var item = {item_id: line_item.menu_item_id, header: line_item.menu_item_header, quantity: line_item.quantity, locations: locations }
  this.items.push(item);
```

Why in this case would item be updated to the last value?

In the table, the results are:

```
test item  3 5 8 
spiced shrimp with horseradish cocktail sauce (per dozen) 9 5 8 
dates with bacon & parmesan (per dozen) 5 5 8 
marcona almonds (serves 8) 6 5 8 
marinated olives (serves 8) 8 5 8
```

and should be

```
test item  3 3 0 
spiced shrimp with horseradish cocktail sauce (per dozen) 9 2 7 
dates with bacon & parmesan (per dozen) 5 5 0 
marcona almonds (serves 8) 6 0 6 
marinated olives (serves 8) 8 0 8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of most problems in your existing code is reusing the same objects - elements of `this.locations` and `this.orderPickupTimes` arrays - again and again as you pass those through `createNewItem`. Augment those lines in your code:

```
// instead of var location = this.locations[j];
var location = Object.assign({}, this.locations[j]);

// and within the internal loop
// instead of var order_pickup_time = this.orderPickupTimes[k];
var order_pickup_time = Object.assign({}, this.orderPickupTimes[k]);
```

... and see the difference it makes.

Still, it's only part of the problem. The key idea of your code is storing -alongside each 'item' object - the whole list of locations and pickup times, having the ones with some orders set their 'quantity' attribute changed.

But to do this, you need to differentiate between the items already processed (with their structures already filled) - and fresh items. It's cumbersome, yes, but might work with something like this:

```
 var locations = [];
 var item = this.items.find(it => it.item_id === line_item.menu_item_id);
 if (item) {
     locations = item.locations;
 }
 else {
     item = {item_id: line_item.menu_item_id, header: line_item.menu_item_header, quantity: 0, locations: locations };
     this.items.push(item);
 }
```

... and have this repeated all the time you need to choose between creating a new location or orderPickupTime - or reusing the existing ones.

Here's [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raina77ow/nL5jfeft/) illustrating this approach.

---

Still, I'd change two major parts here.

First, I'd create a dedicated - private - function to group the order items by their locations and order pickup times. Something like this:

```
function _groupItemsByOrders(orders) {
  return orders.reduce(function(groupedItems, order) {
    var locationId = order.location_id;
    var orderPickupTimeKey = order.order_pickup_time_short;
    order.line_items.forEach(function(lineItem) {
      if (!groupedItems.hasOwnProperty(lineItem.menu_item_id)) {
        groupedItems[lineItem.menu_item_id] = {
          header: lineItem.menu_item_header,
          quantity: 0,
          locations: {}
        };
      }
      var groupedItem = groupedItems[lineItem.menu_item_id];

      if (!groupedItem.locations.hasOwnProperty(locationId)) {
        groupedItem.locations[locationId] = {};
      }
      var groupedItemLocation = groupedItem.locations[locationId];

      if (!groupedItemLocation.hasOwnProperty(orderPickupTimeKey)) {
        groupedItemLocation[orderPickupTimeKey] = 0;
      }

      groupedItemLocation[orderPickupTimeKey] += lineItem.quantity;
      groupedItem.quantity += lineItem.quantity;
    });

    return groupedItems;
  }, {});
}
```

Second, I'd rearranged that template so that it takes the order of locations and orderPickupTimes from header arrays, then maps it to groupedData. Something like this:

```
  <tr v-for="(item, item_id) in groupedItems">
      <td>{{item_id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.header}}</td>
      <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
      <template v-for="location in locations">
        <td v-for="opt in orderPickupTimes">
          {{item.locations[location.id][opt.short]}}
        </td>
      </template>
  </tr>
```

Now, your 'mounted' hook would look like this:

```
mounted(){
  axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f8ceb52d00004d1dad41ec')
    .then(response => {
      this.locations = response.data.locations;
      this.orderPickupTimes = response.data.order_pickup_times;
      this.groupedItems = _groupItemsByOrders(response.data.orders);
    });
}
```

Here's [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raina77ow/ruj7hzcf/5/).

Comment: thx raina - was running around last few days. I upvoted but is it possible to give more info as to why mine isn't working. I added a bounty to reflect the more detail. thx again.

Comment: Updated the answer one more time, providing the demo for the alternate approach. BTW, if you want to check the code behavior with logging, use console.log( JSON.stringify(object)  ) or something similar - otherwise you'll see the _latest_ state of the object - and not the one it has at the moment of logging.